# Raspbian update independent of Motioneyeos update?

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, raspbian, motioneyeos

I have installed Motioneyeos on a Pi Zero and on a Pi2, and it works like a charm in both of them. The control of the 2 systems can be unified on the web server of any one of them. The web interface is clear and allows to customize hundreds aspects of the program. Anything perfect so far.

Trying to understand a little bit how does it work, I have logged to one of the 2 Pis through ssh and I have checked that the OS is kept to a bare minimum. `uname -r` returns 4.19.65.

On the web interface of the app it is possible to check if the last version of the program is the one running. I have checked, and yes, I have the last version.

My question is: does it make sense to upgrade the OS components used by the program (`apt update`, `apt dist-upgrade`) even if the last version of the program is the one running in my Pis? Apt is not even installed, so the first thing would be to bring it there and install it, but I am afraid that if I update the OS, the program may stop to work...

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself thanks to the feedback received in another forum. Motioneyeos is an embedded software based on [Buildroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buildroot) and as such it is not possible to install any package on it. To be able to install a package on Motioneyeos, Motioneyeos has to be installed on an full OS as Raspbian following the instructions in Motioneyeos web [==>>](https://superuser.com/questions/1157148/how-to-install-packages-on-distributions-that-dont-have-apt)